# @RefreshScope not working with @Configuration and @PropertySource

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Here is my config class

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MemcacheProperties {

    @Value("${watchdog.token}")
    private  String token ;

    @Bean
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

Here is my class which consumes above class

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class MemCacheService {

    @Autowired
    private MemcacheProperties properties;

   @Override
   public String get(String key) 
   {
              System.out.println("Property value:"+ properties.getToken());
   }
}
```

After changing value of watchdog.token in application.properties , I fired

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/refresh
```

I got the following response:

```
[
    "watchdog.token"
]
```

Still when MemcacheService's get method is called old configuration is printed .What is going wrong here?

PS:My application is a spring boot application

Comment: You don't need to use `@Bean` on getToken() method, I think that is the issue, as call to @Bean methods in Configuration classes is intercepted and returned the previous bean if already created.

Comment: thank you so much that indeed was the issue

Comment: PS: I didn't even need to add @RefreshScope in my MemCacheService class.However , I read it in this reference doc :

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope

that it is necessary for the classes depending on the configuration, to themselves be in RefreshScope.

Can someone comment on this?